# Git does not track modified files

Tags: git, npm

I have a npm project when i run

```
npm start
```

It creates a bundle of files named like `*-bundle.gz`

When I do minor changes in files like `font.php` and run `npm start` again, new files `*font-bundle.gz` are created with new modification date.

But when i do `git status` , It just displays :

```
modified content : font.php
```

It does not track *font-bundle.gz ,

But when i do more changes in `font.php` then run `npm start` and  do `git status`  it displays :

```
modified content : font.php
*font-bundle.gz
```

So, How could i make git to record all changes even the minor ones.??

Comment: `git add *font-bundle.gz`, but generally it makes little sense to track generated files in a repository.

Comment: Do you have a .gitignore file? Is it explicitly excluding .gz files?

Comment: @MadPhysicist  I have a .gitignore file but it does exclude .gz files. As i already mentioned it tracks the file on major changes . 
Maybe it has to do something with size as .gz files are compressed, not sure though.

Comment: @Martin I created a bundle on my development and i push the bundle to production thats why i want it tracked.

Comment: Git does not differentiate between major and minor changes

Comment: There is a high chance you're missing something out here. As Mas Physicist said git does not differentiate bw files. If the content is the same it will track the file name and not the content, that the max as "untracking" goes.

Answer (score 0):

> When I do minor changes in files like font.php and run npm start
>   again, new files *font-bundle.gz are created with new modification
>   date.

Git doesn't do anything with date git track the changes of the files but comparing it last file it has and if it finds any changes in the content then it shows in git status and commit the changes only instead of the file. So please make sure content of *font-bundle.gz is also getting changed after the minor changes.

> There is no matter of date so please check if newly generated file
>   have any content difference as well or just the same content file is
>   replaced or updated.

Comment: Thanks, as i checked that the changes are reflected that means the gz file is updated. 
Is it possible that the git isnot tracking the changes as .gz files are minified and converted to a single line.?

Comment: @AnmolRastogi Actually while it compressing the file is the compressed content is same or different? have you verified that? unzip before and after file and check the content manually not from the upper like date etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you are telling that `.gz` file is not ignored in the `.gitignore`, I suspect that `.gz` file is part of a separate folder & the folder itself is ignored in the `.gitignore` file.

Otherwise, I would suggest you to specifically unignore the `.gz` files in the `.gitignore` as given below.

```
#unignore gz files 
!*.gz
```

Comment: I checked not the case. 

My gitignore : 

`/node_modules

/public/storage

/public/temp
/vendor
/.idea
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
.env
.DS_Store
/config/session.php
/webpack.config.js
/resources/assets/component/Helpers/env.js
.do.cfg
.do.state

/public/robots.txt`

And my gz files are in public/js folder